# Creating Vue component dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I display all articles in one component. I want to add 'Read more' button to each article and open the whole article by click. Article page should contain full information from API and should have its route path.
I need some kind of dynamic registering components.
What is the best approach?

I use
vuetify@2.6.11
└── vue@2.6.14

Comment: Sounds interesting. What have you done so far?

Comment: App.superiorprediction.com , on button soon, i want to open that prediction and display content of it with url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
If someone needs it, here's the solution:
I edited the component in config.js

```
{
    path: '/view:name/:id',
    component: View,
    props: true
},
```

Where:name and :id is provided when pushing:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/view-'+prop , params: {name: prop, id: p.id } });
```

And then I could directly access these props from the component View and my URL looks as expected.